# Creating a single CommonJS module from several TypeScript classes

Tags: node.js, typescript, commonjs, grunt-ts

I'm trying to work out the best way to split my application into a few CommonJS modules that can be consumed by other applications.

I have 5 TS classes, and I'd like to bundle them as a single CommonJS module.  I then intend to publish this module to a private NPM repo, so it can be consumed by other applications.  Ideally I'd like to package the relevant *.d.ts definition files with it.

What's the best way to do this?  I'm using external TS modules, but these produce a separate CommonJS module per TS class.

Answer (score 18):

As far as i know typescript doesn't support combining external modules yet. From their wiki on codeplex:

> TypeScript has a one-to-one correspondence between external module source files and their emitted JS files. One effect of this is that it's not possible to use the --out compiler switch to concatenate multiple external module source files into a single JavaScript file.

However, you can do a trick by using **internal modules** in typescript, since the tsc compiler has the ability to compile them into a single file, and then you can just add one more file with a `module.exports` directive for the whole namespace to make it a CommonJS module.

Here is a step by step example. Let's say you have the following internal modules split into three files:

**Validation.ts**:

```
module Validation {
    export interface StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string): boolean;
    }
}
```

**ZipCodeValidator.ts**

```
/// <reference path="Validation.ts" />
module Validation {
    var numberRegexp = /^[0-9]+$/;
    export class ZipCodeValidator implements StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string) {
            return s.length === 5 && numberRegexp.test(s);
        }
    }
}
```

**LettersOnlyValidator.ts**

```
/// <reference path="Validation.ts" />
module Validation {
    var lettersRegexp = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    export class LettersOnlyValidator implements StringValidator {
        isAcceptable(s: string) {
            return lettersRegexp.test(s);
        }
    }
}
```

If you compile these with with the --out parameter in the `tsc compiler` you can combine them into a single file. However, that doesn't make them a CommonJS module. To export them you use a trick to add one more ts file called **ValidationExport.ts** containing the export directive for the namespace:

```
var module: any = <any>module;
module.exports = Validation;
```

And then you can run the tsc command to compile everything to a single file called "validationmodule.js":

```
tsc --out validationmodule.js Validation.ts ZipCodeValidator.ts LettersOnlyValidator.ts ValidationExport.ts
```

The output is a CommonJS module you can use in Node.js:

```
var Validation = require("./validationmodule");

var zipCodeValidator = new Validation.ZipCodeValidator();
var lettersOnylValidator = new Validation.LettersOnlyValidator();

console.log(zipCodeValidator.isAcceptable("16211"));
console.log(lettersOnylValidator.isAcceptable("5555"));
```

Comment: Thanks, great response. I guess this then leads me to the question: what's the drawback of using internal modules? I stopped using them a while back as managing script dependencies was a faff.

Comment: Internal modules are just namespaces. They shouldn't pose any limitation in your code. In my example above you have script dependencies and it works fine. If you have a more complex dependency scenario that didn't work you can post it as a question ;)

Comment: I'm having trouble implementing this solution.  Specifically, when I run the line `tsc --out validationmodule.js Validation.ts [...] ValidationExport.ts`, tsc raises the error `TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.` when it attempts to process `ValidationExport.ts`

Comment: @Jthorpe i have updated my answer with a ValidationExport.ts code that should make the compiler happy.

Comment: Thanks!  I was just about to post a similar fix using this declaration `declare var module;` but you beat me to the punch by a few seconds...

Comment: I like the simple trick, thanks a lot. I even loaded my js file in a browser. There I got an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'exports' of undefined", so I changed my line to: `var module: any = <any>module || {};` and seems to work everywhere.

Comment: You sir, have made my day with this post.  I've been trying solutions that only partially resolve my issues, but this idea has done it 100%.  Thank you! :*

Answer (score 1):

Having a separate CommonJS module per file is completely appropriate. All the `require` calls in TypeScript will translate to CommonJS `require` calls in JavaScript, and the `.d.ts` files will be picked up in the process. (If you're doing something silly like `require`ing classes outside your source directory... stop.)

You would only need to consider a packaging step if you intended to use this NPM package in other applications, in which case look into [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)